# Difference between bacteria and bacteroids?

Tags: bacteriology, nitrogen-cycle

During nodule formation *Rhizobium* is converted to bacteroids. What's the difference between them?

Comment: I edited your title: *Bacteroides* is a Genus of bacteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacteroids are the endosymbiotic forms of rhizobia (in the root nodules of leguminous plants).

---

Löhnis & Hansen (1921) J Agric Res 20: 543-556; emphasis mine:

> It is not superfluous to emphasize once more that persistence in
>   calling these forms **"bacteroids"** is by no means to be recommended.
>   They are **true bacteria, not foreign bodies looking like bacteria,** as
>   Frank's pupil Brunchorst erroneously believed. To speak of a
>   "bacteroid" growth of bacteria is no less absurd than it would be to
>   speak of a "fungoid" growth of fungi.

https://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/IND43966363/PDF

---

Gerson & Patel (1975) Appl Microbiol 30: 193-198; emphasis mine:

> *Rhizobium* is an aerobe, existing as a free-living bacterium in soil or
>   as a partially anaerobic symbiont in the root nodules of leguminous
>   plants. It is in the **symbiotic form (bacteroid),** which is frequently
>   **morphogenetically different,** that **nitrogen fixation** takes place.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC365797/

MacKenzie et al. (1973) J Bacteriol. 113: 387-393; emphasis mine:

> [C]hanges [accompany] the **transformation** from the free-living rod
>   forms to the nitrogen-fixing bacteroid forms. (...) During the
>   transformation into the bacteroidal state **the wall decreased in
>   thickness,** became **less rigid,** and developed a particulate surface.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC251641/